# Delay to avoid cocurrent modification

Tags: java, error-handling

I was attempting to remove items from an `ArrayList` while iterating through it, only to find out that Java doesn't like that.  So I quickly wrote up a `Delay` that I could pass operations to so I could run them later.

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Delay {
    private Set<Runnable> tasks = new HashSet<Runnable>();

    public Delay(){}
    public Delay(Runnable... tasks){
        for(Runnable task : tasks) this.tasks.add(task);
    }

    public void add(Runnable task){
        this.tasks.add(task);
    }
    public void run(){
        for(Runnable task : tasks) task.run();
        tasks.clear();
    }
}
```

Code in use (in a card game):

```
Delay delay = new Delay();

...

// if a hand has no cards, remove it from play
for(Hand hand : hands) if(hand.size() == 0) delay.add(() -> hands.remove(hand));
delay.run();
```

Is there a flaw in my solution?  Or does Java already have a method of handling this, making my code redundant?  Any points of improvement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using java 8, there's the `removeIf` method ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)).

You can use it like this:

```
hands.removeIf(h -> h.size() == 0);
```

Or, if `Hand` is a `Collection` of some sort,

```
hands.removeIf(Hand::isEmpty)
```

Comment: That's wonderful, especially since Iterators are giving me a hard time! I learned on Java 7 and have been picking up pieces of 8 (no pun intended) for a while now. Also not terribly immersed in higher level techniques; lambda functions still kinda blow my mind!

Comment: Also yes, Hand is a List actually, so that works out well!

Comment: `removeIf(Predicate)` should be the right approach, but once again it is implementation-dependent when it comes to concurrent modification... As the Javadoc goes, the default implementation falls back to the `Iterator` approach, and `ArrayList` may still throw `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: I don't think OP's question is about the list being modified from another thread.  He is just trying to remove elements from the list based on the predicate, which is exactly what `removeIf` does.  @ndm, if I misunderstood your question and you ARE modifying the list from another thread, please say so.  It would certainly change the answer.

Comment: @Misha Nope, you had the right idea! Sorry if I was unclear. As of now it's all one thread. But if `removeIf` isn't safe for multithreading, it might be good to know for future reference.

Comment: @ndm Adding or removing elements to a collection is never thread-safe without some specific guarantees either from the specific collection implementation or from external synchronization you do yourself.

Comment: @Misha the only reason I mentioned that is because @ndm13 mentioned something about concurrent modification in @Vogel612's `Iterator`-based answer... just something to be aware about for the OP. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Yes java already has that. What you're looking for is an [`Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html):

```
Iterator<Hand> handIt = hands.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Hand current = handIt.next();
    if (current.size() == 0) {
        handIt.remove();
    }
}
```

This can be simplified / changed to:

```
for (Iterator<Hand> handIt = hands.iterator(); handIt.hasNext(); ) {
    Hand current = handIt.next();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot!  I've used Iterators before, but for some reason thought they fell prey to the same cocurrent modification issues that Lists had.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: @ndm13 an `Iterator` is backed by the `List` implementation, so using a concurrent-friendly one like [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) may be something of interest.